# Downloaded a torrent of cracked software – think my Mac is now infected

Tags: virus, torrent

So I downloaded a torrent of Apple Final Cut Pro.

There was a quick pop of either Terminal or Green looking terminal. The said application (green Terminal) opened and close, opened and close, and so on for a short period of time. It looked fishy so I didn't know whether it's a virus or not.

Can someone help me. Am I safe? Should I factory reset?

Comment: I upvoted this question because I think others should see this and it should serve as a warning to others.  **NEVER, NEVER, NEVER pirate software**.  Besides being both illegal and unethical you open yourself up to malware.  Google "ransomware" and see how people are having their data held hostage.

Comment: The question is unclear. When did the (green) Terminal window appear? After opening/installing FinalCut Pro or while downloading? Which torrent client do you use? Did you have to enter an admin password at some point of time?

Comment: When I first open the Final Cut Pro, the terminal window appeared. The downloading process was normal. Luckily I just reseted my Mac a last week, no information was on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not safe. Your personal documents, contacts, and private information are at risk.

The behaviour you are seeing is not part of Apple's Final Cut Pro. The odd terminal like behaviour suggests you do have a rogue process or application on your Mac.

[Search for a guide](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+remove+virus+from+Mac&t=osx) about how to remove malware and viruses from your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The same behavior happened to me even though it was a validly signed copy of Final Cut Pro.

Run spctl on the app using `spctl --assess --verbose /path/to/app` in Terminal. If it outputs "Mac App Store", you are safe, because the file hasn't been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading a torrent is never a good move. It's highly likely your computer's been compromised. Here are some steps to take (in listed order) to take cautionary action.

1. Delete the torrent and all of its files from your computer.
2. Put up a firewall by going to System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Firewall > Turn On Firewall (you may have to get access with an administrator username and password).
3. Enable FileVault, which encrypts your hard drive, by navigating to System Preferences > Security and Privacy > FileVault. Again, administrator keys may be required. Be sure to remember the password you use to encrypt the disk.
4. If your computer is actively being jeopardized, a factory reset is in order. Follow [this guide](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-reset-macbook-restore-your-mac-original-factory-settings-3494564/) to restore your computer. You'll need your FileVault password, and administrator keys.

Comment: Is it safe to plug in my passport (storage device) with my yesterday time machine backup and reset it back to that day?

Comment: @31i45, I'd say NO, do not attach anything while the system is actively infected and your should have disconnected from the Internet immediately when the issue occurred.  You should reboot the system to Recovery HD and wipe the drive and reinstall OS X, then restore your user data from Time Machine.

Comment: @ Angelplayer, I have to disagree with your order of steps to take.  There is no way I'd ever start an encryption process on a system that may be compromised by a virus or malware! 1. Disconnect immediately from the Internet before shutting down the system. 2. Reboot to Recovery HD, or better yet an OS  X USB Installer created on a known good uninfected working system, wipe the HDD and reinstall OS X.  Then if you want to encrypt the drive, okay.

Comment: I'm not that worry about information being taken out, as my computer, reseted last week, has no information in it. All I want is to restore back to yesterday state.

Comment: Point 2 and 3 are not recommended/not helpful. Point 2 should be modified to "Disconnect from internet completely". Enabling the firewall doesn't help for outgoing calls. Enabling FileVault doesn't help much either because the content is  available in the user context (= any rogue process runs in the same context!) even if the whole disk is encrypted.

Comment: I open the mac in safe mode. The problem I have is my WD My Passsport is password protected and when I go to "restore from time machine", mac can't find my disk. What do I do?

Comment: I made a new one

Comment: @31i45 firewalls will do nothingif your already infected. Encryption will do nothingi you are already infected. At the most, encryption might make it more difficult for the virus to function  as it was designed, and could potentially cause it to malfunction and expose itself. Either way, those two options are silly in a case like this. Use someone elses clean mac and create a bootable usb installer of mac os. Then use that to reinstall your system. Thats your best bet.